# Does checking out a branch with git after doing git fetch still goto the origin?

Tags: git, version-control

If I have a remote server setup with my local repo and I do a git fetch for the first time, if there were 10 remote branches, I would now have 10 remote tracking branches from what I've read.

From what I've also gathered these remote tracking branches are pointers to those remote branches rather than actual full local copies of the code on those branches...is that correct?

My follow up then is if I was to checkout one of these remote branches after a git fetch, does git still need to connect to the remote to get all the code or would it simply switch to the remote tracking branch on the local machine which already has all the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've also gathered these remote tracking branches are pointers to those remote branches rather than actual full local copies of the code on those branches...is that correct?

No, it is not correct.

Git branches are just a name and a commit ID. There's nothing special about remote branches, except you don't commit to them.

When you fetch you download a full copy of every commit. Each commit knows which commit came before it (or in the case of a merge, two or more commits). This is the "history". Git is very efficient at storing and transmitting that history.

> My follow up then is if I was to checkout one of these remote branches after a git fetch, does git still need to connect to the remote to get all the code or would it simply switch to the remote tracking branch on the local machine which already has all the code?

Git already has a complete copy of the repository. When you `git checkout origin/main` Git switches to the already downloaded commit that origin/main points at.

Only a handful of Git commands do any network access. The primary ones are `git push`, `git fetch` and `git pull` (which is just a fetch + a merge).

Comment: Thanks, one small follow up, I wasn't sure if that was the case because if you had a server with hundreds of remote branches or maybe even more, wouldn't it be inefficient to keep getting the full repos of so many branches if you were never going to use them?

Comment: @jobe: Maybe. Maybe not. How expensive is it to fetch a branch? The answer is 42. (Apologies to Douglas Adams, and it's actually more like 40, unless you add the other overhead, which generally puts it around 100 bytes.) But you don't actually fetch *branches*. You actually fetch *commits*. Once you have the branch name (including the overhead that puts it up around 100 bytes or so), your Git then may, or may not if it already has them, need to fetch the *commits*.

Comment: So, the correct question is not about the *branches*, but rather about the *commits*. How many commits do you get that you never use? How expensive is that? When (and where) do you pay this price? The answers to *those* questions are complicated, but usually you've paid most of the expense when you ran `git clone`. After that it's usually quite cheap.

Comment: @jobe LIke torek said, you fetch commits and the commits are all linked one after the other. Let's say the main branch can reach five commits, and a branch off main which adds two more commits. Once you've fetched the five commits reachable from main you only need to fetch two more commits to get the branch. Also a repo with hundreds of branches is pretty pathological.

Comment: @Schwern so in that last example when I do a git fetch on main, I will get those 5 commits but will I also get the other 2 commits, or all the other commits in the repo i.e. everything? or do I need to checkout those individual branches and when I git fetch on them will I get their respective commits?

Comment: @jobe By default, `git-fetch` updates every branch, and gets any new branches. You'll get every commit (every commit you don't already have) which is needed to complete the all the branches' history. This might sound like a lot, but most branches share most of their history and will only have a handful of unique commits.

Comment: Thanks that is good to know, so if you git fetch and then checkout a branch that you haven't checked out before, you will have that branch with all it's latest commits alread and you will be checking them out from your machine locally i.e. you're not making a request to github again to get that branch?

Comment: @jobe Yes. You are working with a full mirror of the repository. All the repository commands, checkout, diff, commit, log, etc... are happening on your local snapshot. This is the heart of [distributed version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control). Git does not update your local repository for you, you have to tell it to do so. See [Working With Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) and [Remote Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)